# Flask: How to Authenticate with Flask-Redis and Redis

Tags: python, redis, flask

How can I send "AUTH" command to authenticate the connection using Flask-Redis in Flask app?
I know Flask-Redis is just a small wrapper for redis-py but I can't figure out how to handle the authorization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this Flask_Redis: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Redis/0.0.5 ?

If so, there is a better way to handle this than placing it in the URL. According to the docs, in your Flask config place the following:

```
REDIS_HOST = "localhost"
REDIS_PASSWORD = "password"
REDIS_PORT = 6379
```

If placing the config in code, as in your example:

```
app.config["REDIS_PASSWORD"] = 'password'
```

Doing this in the config should be more maintainable and configurable without modifying code.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have found how to solve this.
You can pass the password in URL, example:

```
...
app.config["REDIS_URL"] = 'redis://:password@localhost/0'
redis_db = Redis(app, "REDIS")
...
```